# Transfer an image as byte array

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, arrays

I'm trying to send an image from a 'server', whose purpose is to send images, to a 'client' that is an Android device. The socket between then is stay open and images keep on coming. The problem is:

1. I dont know the size of the image (it can change);
2. the image is not BMP format.

In my code below:

1. the client doesn't stop reading after the image is transfered (I don't get `-1` when it is read), it will stop just when the socket is closed;
2. after it has finished reading, the input stream is not cleared and the same image is read over and over again.

At first I tried to send 2 BMP images whose size I know (both the same size). Here is the server code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(4488);
            System.out.println("Waiting for a connection . . . . ");
            Socket socket = s.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected!");
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            File myImageFile = new File("c:\\1\\a.bmp");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myImageFile);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int) myImageFile.length()];
            byte[] tmp = new byte[0];
            byte[] myArrayImage = new byte[0];
            int len = 0 ;
            int total = 0;

            while( (len = fis.read(data)) != -1 ) {
                total += len;
                tmp = myArrayImage;
                myArrayImage = new byte[total];
                System.arraycopy(tmp,0,myArrayImage,0,tmp.length);
                System.arraycopy(data,0,myArrayImage,tmp.length,len);
            }

            //

            fis.close();

            dataOutputStream.write(myArrayImage);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            myImageFile = new File("c:\\1\\b.bmp");
            fis = new FileInputStream(myImageFile);
            data = new byte[(int) myImageFile.length()];
            tmp = new byte[0];
            myArrayImage = new byte[0];
            len = 0 ;
            total = 0;

            while( (len = fis.read(data)) != -1 ) {
                total += len;
                tmp = myArrayImage;
                myArrayImage = new byte[total];
                System.arraycopy(tmp,0,myArrayImage,0,tmp.length);
                System.arraycopy(data,0,myArrayImage,tmp.length,len);
            }

            fis.close();

            dataOutputStream.write(myArrayImage);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            socket.close();
            s.close();
```

Here is the client code:

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] byteChunk = null;
    int c;

    if (_dataInputStream != null) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            try {
                byteChunk = new byte[1024];

                while ((c = _dataInputStream.read(byteChunk)) != -1){
                    buffer.write(byteChunk, 0, byteChunk.length);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer.toByteArray(), 0, buffer.size());

            if (bitmap != null) {
                _handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        _iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        _iv.invalidate();
                    }
                }); 
            }

                buffer.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as I said, the client is stuck on the while loop until the socket is closed and then (no matter how many images I send, because I created in the client side a bytearray that fits only for 1 image) it keeps reading this first image all the time.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

P.s. If the image is not a BMP will the decode I wrote in the client side code work? The real image I want to send is a PNG.

Comment: Are you terminating on a NULL byte at the end of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for the client to know when to stop reading from the stream unless you use some mechanism to indicate the end of input.

A simple fix would be to use a fixed length (four bytes, an int would suffice for most images) header that you write to the stream that tells the client the length of the following data. The client then reads that number of bytes from the stream before stopping and waiting for an other header or closing the stream.

An other approach would be to use a file end delimiter to inform the client that the end of input has been encountered.

You are going to have to write some additional data (metadata) in the stream besides the image itself unless you close the stream after input.

Comment: I tried to add a int before the image but still - the stream that the client is reading from doesn't get empty while I read it, and therefor I keep on reading the same image.

Answer (score 1):

you can first send the size of image byte array and then in the while loop read the byte until reach the size like this:

```
DataInputStream in = conn.openDataInputStream();

            // read a length first
            int length = in.readInt();


            if (length <= 0) {
                throw new IOException("Can't read a length");
            }

            // read the image now
            imgData = new byte[length];
            length = 0;

            while (length != imgData.length) {
                int n = in.read(imgData, length, imgData.length - length);

                if (n == -1) {
                    throw new IOException("Can't read a image data");
                }

                length += n;
            }

            in.close();
```

[this is an edited version of this](http://cccufcg.googlecode.com/svn-history/r21/trunk/ImageTuner/src/imagetuner/bluetooth/BTImageClient.java)

be careful that the size of your image is int and it has more than one byte, then you need to use writeint.

Answer (score 0):

Only looked at your client code, but this is not going to fit in a comment.  You need to rethink what you're doing; your thinking (I do the same thing on *my* first attempts) is sort-of human-based rather than computer-based.  In other words, your code makes sense to *me*, a human, but I don't really know why, and it won't make sense to the computer.

Main point:  There's no exit from your `while (true)` loop--it's infinite.  I'd expect it to repeat the last read into `bitmap' repeatedly.

First, I'd get rid of the `sleep` code.  It's confusing the issue now and you can put it back later if it helps some how.  (I don't think it will, your read will do all the blocking necessary.)  Then you need an end-of-image marker or something to break you out of the read loop when a complete image has been read.  (Or have it trigger image handling code placed *inside* this loop.)

And finally, you need an end-of-file, or end-of-*images* marker to kick you out of the `while (true)` loop.  (Back to the "Main point".)

Answer (score 0):

Hi but if you want to read the `jpeg` file then you can use this code

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
int count = 0;
do
{
    count += in.read(bytes, count, bytes.length - count);
}while (!(count > 4 && bytes[count - 2] == (byte) -1 && bytes[count - 1] == (byte) -39));
```

But i am not able to understand how to read `PNG` format

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send a PNG, read a little about the format ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)). Each chunk is length-prefixed, so you can send it raw over a network and know when it is finished!